# Best way to check url contain a String and QueryString in PHP

Tags: php, query-string

I am trying to detect whether a url contains a **string** or a **string with querystring**, then give it a different function.

The code below is all I can think of and it's doesn't work.

What is the best way to check this?

```
url 1 = http://example.com/index.php

url 2 = http://example.com/index.php?some-test-page

if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index')){
    $xurl="http://example2.com/photos/";
} else {
    $req_url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $xurl=('http://example2.com/photos/'   . $req_url . '');
}
```

Comment: yes, if there's a query string i want to append it like this http://example2.com/photos/query-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a query string, it will populate [the `$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). Just check for that and add it back using [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) if needed (this will ensure any escaping is taken care of.)

```
$xurl = "http://example2.com/photos/";
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    $xurl .= "?" . http_build_query($_GET);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the '?' in requesturi rather than index.

```
url 1 = http://example.com/index.php
url 2 = http://example.com/index.php?some-test-page

if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') === false ){

  $xurl="http://example2.com/photos/";

    }
else{
    $req_url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    $xurl=('http://example2.com/photos/'   . $req_url . '');
    }
```

Comment: An explanation of what the problem is would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Split URL into pieces with parse_url, then examine closer what you need...
http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php